# Handle HTML checkboxes without javascript?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Is there any way to handle `(detect checked, count checked etc)` dynamically created checkboxes in HTML without Javascript? Php echoes these checkboxes and I dont know much Javascript.

Simple functions that could detect if the user, for example, has clicked exactly 6 checkboxes then it would process the  element in Php.

I'm making a "Edit Featured Friends" kind of page in a social networking site context. Thanks!

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. If you want an event to fire on the client, then you will have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your checkboxes are being generated something like this:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" /> Some label';
```

Then on your server-side code receiving the POST request you can do this:

```
if( count($_POST['boxes']) != 6) die("Please check exactly 6 boxes");
```